# Playing audio on a Waveshare audio module

Tags: pi-pico, micropython, circuitpython

I've bought a Pico Audio module - assuming, maybe incorrectly, that being built to fit the Pico, speakers included etc it would be reasonably straightforward to get it working.

https://thepihut.com/products/pico-audio-audio-module-for-raspberry-pi-pico-inc-speakers

The example Micropython code they supply (https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Pico-Audio) works and I hear a tone from the speakers, so confident that the speakers, volume etc work - but any documentation or example code I've managed to track down for either MicroPython or CircuitPython seem to assume one less connection than this device has - e.g https://learn.adafruit.com/mp3-playback-rp2040/pico-i2s-mp3 - whereas the Waveshare module also has a "master clock input" pin that doesn't seem to be supported by this library.

I've tried ignoring this (that pin didn't exist at all on an earlier version of this board) and running the example code with

`audio = audiobusio.I2SOut(board.GP28, board.GP27, board.GP22)`

this throws an exception:

`ValueError: Bit clock and word select must be sequential pins: Bit clock and word select must be sequential pins`

and also tried wiring pins 27 and 28 the opposite way around (so GP28 on the Pico wired to 27 on the audio board, and vice versa) - so I could call the "correct" pins sequentially which does run without exception, but still no audio output.

Has anyone successfully managed to use one of these or similar and able to point me in the right direction? (or able to suggest a better alternative)

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to either through CircuitPython. Micro works with their code, but their code writes some strange assembly language to generate the buffer for the sine wave.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).